# Android bluetooth socket.connect fails; Throws java IO exception

Tags: android, io, bluetooth, java-io

I'm using a code derived from Bluetooth tutorial on Android Developer page.
My app tries to connect to a BT weighing scale and record the weight information.

My program throws an error when it attempts to perform a BluetoothSocket.connect();
The program runs as a Bluetooth client/slave in order to receive the data from a BT device.
The user sees a list of paired devices on the screen and clicks on a particular device in order to connect to it.

Hence, when the user clicks on a specific device, the app tries to connect to it since the device is already paired beforehand.

The app obtains a BluetoothSocket but fails to perform the connect()

I have tried to just establish a connection with other Bluetooth devices but I always end up getting the same error over and over.

The following is the java code for connectThread:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
     
        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;
            Log.i(tag, "construct");
            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                Log.i(tag, "get socket failed");
                
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }
     
        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.i(tag, "connect - run");
            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.i(tag, "connect - succeeded");
            } catch (IOException connectException) {    Log.i(tag, "connect failed");
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }
     
            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
       
            mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
        }
```

The entire code for the app can be found  **[here](http://pastebin.com/kaBthsYk)**

The following is the log I obtained while running the app:

```
01-01 01:46:00.359: I/ActivityManager(1553): Displayed com.test.bluetooth/.Main_Activity: +579ms
01-01 01:46:00.953: D/BluetoothService(1553): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(00:10:C6:2E:CB:C3)
01-01 01:46:00.968: D/BluetoothService(1553): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(00:19:15:66:C4:2D)
01-01 01:46:00.984: D/BluetoothService(1553): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(00:1A:88:00:01:25)
01-01 01:46:01.000: D/BluetoothService(1553):   uuid(system): 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 1
01-01 01:46:04.421: I/debugging(2400): construct
01-01 01:46:04.421: D/BluetoothEventLoop(1553): Property Changed: Discovering : false
01-01 01:46:04.421: I/debugging(2400): in click listener
01-01 01:46:04.421: E/BluetoothService.cpp(1553): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
01-01 01:46:04.429: E/BluetoothService.cpp(1553): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
01-01 01:46:04.437: I/debugging(2400): connect - run
01-01 01:46:04.437: V/BluetoothDiscoveryReceiver(1864): Received: android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED
01-01 01:46:04.445: E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(1553): onCreateDeviceResult: D-Bus error: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists (Already Exists)
01-01 01:46:05.484: D/BluetoothEventLoop(1553): Device property changed: 00:10:C6:2E:CB:C3 property: Connected value: true
01-01 01:46:06.554: D/BluetoothService(1553): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(00:10:C6:2E:CB:C3)
01-01 01:46:06.562: D/BluetoothService(1553):   uuid(application): 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 1
01-01 01:46:06.562: D/BluetoothService(1553): Making callback for 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb with result 1
01-01 01:46:06.562: I/debugging(2400): connect failed
01-01 01:46:06.562: W/System.err(2400): java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
01-01 01:46:06.562: W/System.err(2400):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)
01-01 01:46:06.562: W/System.err(2400):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:216)
01-01 01:46:06.562: W/System.err(2400):     at com.test.bluetooth.Main_Activity$ConnectThread.run(Main_Activity.java:326)
01-01 01:46:10.132: D/BluetoothEventLoop(1553): Device property changed: 00:10:C6:2E:CB:C3 property: Connected value: false
01-01 01:47:05.914: D/SurfaceFlinger(1311): About to give-up screen, flinger = 0x41876af0
```

*Any/all help in order to set up a basic BT connection is greatly appreciated.*

Thank you.

Comment: Okay, stupid Q: What version of android is the tutorial written for,  and which are you running? It's possible some errors may originate there if you're working with something too old (or too new!) from your current environment.

Comment: @RachelKeslensky I'm using API level 15 (ICS) for my app but my device runs Jelly Bean. So, my device is running an advanced version of the OS and that shouldn't be a problem in my view.

Answer (score 3):

Check to make sure that the UUID you're using is appropriate for the type of device you're trying to connect to.

Comment: I did use the right UUID. In fact this is the first thing I checked in order to set it right.

It uses the SPP and the UUID I'm using is: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB (As you can see from my entire code)

Answer (score 0):

Got a same problem while connecting to bluetooth device other than mobile. Changing UUID value works for me. Earlier I was using UUID value mention at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatService.java
but that is for mobile bluetooth device then i changed my UUID with 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB and it works